# Apply function to certain groups of columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, p-value

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
1   10    10    20    25    
2   15    20    10    20
3   20    10    15    10
```

I want to calculate a p-value using the scipy stats package. Specifically, I want to get a p-value comparing the first two columns and the last two columns on each row. I have tried to use the scipy stats package, but think I am having trouble indexing the dataframe.

I think the code could look something like this (hypothetical data):

```
from scipy import stats
stats.wilcoxon(df[col1:col2], df[col3:col4])
```

I would then want to append the pvalue back to the dataframe.

The final output would look something like:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  p_value
1   10    10    20    25    0.05
2   15    20    10    20    0.10
3   20    10    15    10    0.02
```

With the two comparisons being the values from col1/col2 vs col3/col4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we may do it with line by line

```
df['p_v'] = df.apply(lambda x : stats.wilcoxon(x['col1':'col2'], x['col3':'col4'])[1],axis=1)
```

Comment: I get this error when I use your suggestion:
`zero_method 'wilcox' and 'pratt' do not work if x - y is zero for all elements.`
But I think this is a rank test problem and not a problem with your line of code. It works if I change the test, thank you so much for your help!